# Problems with Facebook Login Phonegap

Tags: iphone, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

In this momment I'm making a App for a restauran, and I put a section to make a login.
Well, the part where I create users works, and I can Login, but I can't make the login with facebook.

in the login with facebook I'm only need to take some information from the user.
 For the moment I'm using this code:

```
<iframe src=’http://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?client_id=1429098070665777&redirect_uri=http://lafabricadbm.com/pruebas/SDKFB/&fields=[{"name":"name"},{"name":"email"},{"name":"birthday"},]‘></iframe>
```

and works, in the web, but when I make a deploy in IOS, well, doesn't work.

I'm already try with SDK of Facebook to javavascript, but I can't take the information, to fill the form of my App.
As you see I'm only need name, birthday and email.

If someone can help me I will appreciate, than you.

P.D I already check, some solution here, but i didn't find the answer.